# php select from table error

Tags: php, sql, message

I have a problem.

When I try to select data from a table using this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rad = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $rad['user'];
}
```

It works.

When I select data from another table with basically the same code I get an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rad = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $rad['url'];
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the error message I get when I run the second code:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in

Comment: `mysql_query($sql);` -> `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` will give you the error you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is returning FALSE , meaning there is an error in your query.

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

It's possible you have no rights on this table.

Do this to show me the error:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();
```

**PROBLEM FOUND:**

After seeing your mysql error everything is clear.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order' at line 1

You have to chance:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM order";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `order`";
```

Putting order between backticks (“`”),
because `order` is a reserved mysql word for `order by` operations.

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as
>   described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:

From [Mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

Reserved words are listed at Section 9.3, [“Reserved Words”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: This is the error I get:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order' at line 1"

Comment: Ah ok i see you need to put order between single quotes because order is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

*"with basically the same code"* ...

This is most likely due to you lacking a connection. You can troubleshoot using:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/679449) for more troubleshooting steps.

Also, please do not use `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.